# How do I access web accessible resources in my content scripts css file in firefox?

Tags: css, image, firefox, firefox-addon

This is a fairly simple question. To access a web accesible resource that is declared in the manifest.json, we use the browser.runtime.getURL method in any content script javascript. **How do we get an url to the web accessible resource in css?**

Manifest:
`"web_accessible_resources": ["resources/logo.jpg"]`

JavaScript
`browser.runtime.getURL("resources/logo.jpg")`

CSS
`background: url(???)`

Comment: Did you tried to use a css variable like `background: var(--background)` and update it in javascript by using `document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--background', \`url(${browser.runtime.getURL("resources/logo.jpg")})\`)`?

Comment: That is just what I was looking for! I'm guessing it is not possible in pure css?

Comment: Sadly I don't think so

Comment: If it's working in your case should I that as an answer?